# How to get each cell value in each row

Tags: jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller, web

I'm trying to learn asp and now I'm encountering this situation where I have to make a list first of data and then insert it to my database.

I used html table where every entry is append to the table and when the user is satisfied of the list, when the button is save it will insert every data in every row of the table. How can I do this so I can use it to my ajax?

Sample html table:

```
Name     Address     Contact
Dave     Alpha St.   12345
Jade     Delta St.   56789
Elsa     Beta St.    54321
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far yourself

Comment: Two loops, one over columns, one over rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JQuery` `find` method

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#sample").find("tbody tr").each(function() {
    alert($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text());
    alert($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text());
    alert($(this).find("td:eq(2)").text());

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="sample">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Dave</td>
      <td>Alpha St.</td>
      <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jade</td>
      <td>Delta St.</td>
      <td>56789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Elsa</td>
      <td>Beta St.</td>
      <td>54321</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="get"></input>
```